# Trouble with enabling bibliography entries in Winedt editor

Tags: bibliographies, texstudio, winedt, auto-completion

I currently have a tiny problem with enabling `bib` references **autocompletion** when using Winedt editor. Here comes the description: I have a collection of bib reference entries in a `myref.bib` file and I have included it in the `.tex` document `\bibliography{myref}`.
When I want insert a citation for the **first** time, Winedt will show a `pop-up bib list` for choices (this is what I want), see[image]

However, when I want to insert a **second** bib entry in the same place, no `autocompletion` or `pop-up` shows, see[image]

In **TeXStudion**, I do not have such kind of trouble, see[image]

It's not so big trouble, but I wonder how can I fix it-achieving `bib` entries **autocomplete** whenever you want **NOT** just for the first entry. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you ask for help WinEdt support (winedt+list@wsg.net)?

Comment: No, my friend~_~. I have not heard of it before. `wsg.net`, a website for winedt support?@Zarko

Answer (score 1):

It seems that insert multiple bibliographt citations *at the same place* with `autocompletion` in **WinEdt** is *possible* but just *for one shot*. The procedure is as follows (two ciatations here for simplicity): when you first enter `\cite` LaTeX command, you will see a **pop-up** which includes all your bib entries. Select one, see

[image]

After you have chosen your **first** citaion and want to add the **second**, you add a comma `,` after the **citation key** of the first one. Now you can see a new line for your **second** citation, see

[image]

Finally, you click the `Insert` button in the **pop-up**.

That's my own use experience. Triggering the **pop-up** might only be one shot. If there exist customerization settings in **WinEdt** for multiple times triggering, please inform me.